# PHP: file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection refused

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

I am trying to access a second server with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and simple_load_xml and I get
 "failed to open stream: Connection refused"
What can be the result?

```
allow_url_fopen=Yes
allow_url_include=Off
```

is my php.ini values

Comment: 'Connection refused' is almost certainly the second server actively refusing the connection, not a local php-setting. Look at that servers logs.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the 2nd server is rejecting the file, try using [curl](http://www.php.net/curl) to obtain the file instead; the benefit of using curl is that it'll give you helpful debugging information in the event of a failure like this. get_file_content() masks a lot of this helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to the resource is being rejected. Ensure that you can access the resource from the server (Using Lynx for instance).

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is because you need a resource - [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), instead of a string - [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)