# file_get_contents() not working in Linux

Tags: php, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [file_get_content failed to open stream: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098129/file-get-content-failed-to-open-stream-connection-refused)

file_get_content function was not working on Linux vqs332.pair.com 2.6.32-33-server. Either i need to change any setting in my php.ini or some other problem. 
I'm using this function to get latitude and longitude from the address (dynamic).

```
file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=24411+Health+Center+Dr+Suite+200&sensor=false");
```

Plz guide me.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the file and the directory it is in?

Comment: Please elborate on "Not working". Please add any error messages you get (you have enabled error logging, and error_reporting(E_ALL), right?). Please explain what you expect to get, and what you actually get.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that your host has [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) disabled. This is quite common in shared hosting environments and is a sensible security precaution.

In order to get around the problem you will have to download the file with cURL to a local path and use it locally.

e.g.

```
// Remote file we want, and the local file name to use as a temp file
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=24411+Health+Center+Dr+Suite+200&sensor=false';
$localfile = 'mytempfilename.ext';

// Let's go cURLing...
$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen($localfile,'w');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

// Get the data into memory and delete the temp file
$filedata = file_get_contents($localfile);
unlink($localfile);
```

Comment: `The problem is that your host has allow_url_fopen`. In fact, you can't say that for sure.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel Granted, but there has to be a 90% chance that it is the problem, given how often these questions pop up and how often it is the answer... I'll re-word it with 'probably'

Comment: Thanks for your comments i hv changed allow_url_fopen to On in my .htcaess file. Its working now.